# How to calculate the overlap of the orthogonal state?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

This is probably a very obvious question, but I am going through [this problem set](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Evidick/teaching/120_qcrypto/HW1_solutions.pdf) and I don't understand why in 1b) it says that it is obvious that $|\langle\psi_1^\perp|\psi_2\rangle|=\sin\theta$ given that $|\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle| = \cos\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** These inner products are equal to the amplitudes and therefore the squares of their magnitudes sum to one. By Pythagoras theorem $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$, so if one of the amplitudes is $\cos\theta$ then the magnitude of the other must be $|\sin\theta|$.

---

Since $\{|\psi_1\rangle, |\psi_1^\perp\rangle\}$ is a basis, we can expand $|\psi_2\rangle$ as

$$
|\psi_2\rangle = \alpha |\psi_1\rangle + \beta |\psi_1^\perp\rangle\tag1
$$

where $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2=1$. Moreover, since the basis is orthonormal, we can compute $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of inner products

$$
\alpha = \langle \psi_1|\psi_2\rangle \\
\beta = \langle \psi_1^\perp|\psi_2\rangle
$$

as is easy to check by taking the inner product of $(1)$ with the elements of the  dual basis. Now, from $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2=1$ we see that

$$
|\langle \psi_1^\perp|\psi_2\rangle| = |\beta| = \sqrt{1 - |\alpha|^2} = \sqrt{1 - |\langle \psi_1|\psi_2\rangle|^2} = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2\theta} = |\sin\theta|
$$

but $\theta \in (0, \pi)$ so $|\langle \psi_1^\perp|\psi_2\rangle|=\sin\theta$.